# How to access control of one aspx page from code behind of another page

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I need help to rebind a gridview of parent page when data in my child page is saved successfully. How can I do it .Please help

**Update**

I have a aspx page(AdminCity) with a grid view . when i click on add button in this page, it opens a new popup window using following JavaScript in OnClientClick

```
function openPopup() {

             window.open("CityPop.aspx", "_blank", "WIDTH=500,HEIGHT=300,scrollbars=no, menubar=no,resizable=yes,directories=no,location=no");

                      }
```

so this JavaScript opens a new window in which there is a textbox to save data. Now what I want is when data is saved successfully, I want the gridview in the parent page(AdminCity) to rebind/refresh so that it can have the data which I added in textbox.
I am Newbie and someone suggested me that you can access gridview control from popup window page's code behind but I dont know how to do it.

Comment: You don't access controls from another page through the code behind. The pages exist independently of each other. If you want to implement a system for pushing real time content updates out to your users, you might look into SignalR.

Answer (score 0):

You have to share more information. If that is some jquery.UI dialog, or even perhaps a bootstrap dialog, then fine.

However, if you talking about a 100% different tab or browser session that you opened? Nope, not allowed.

Think of this case:

You come to my web site to view a cute cat picture. but, then my code goes and looks for any other browser window open - including one that is doing your banking. So, no, you can't get nor grab other browser windows at all - not allowed and as such would be a huge security risk.

However, you can certainly pop a window up on your current page - jquery.UI dialogs are great for this. However, in near all cases, if you need (or allow) a post-back, then the dialog will of course collapse, since you talking about a page re-load for any plane jane post-back or button click in asp.net land.

So, not really 100% clear by what you mean "parent page". It perhaps may well not mean an actual separate browser windows, and if this is the case, then you may well be able to re-fresh or re-load the grid view in such a case.